# which matrix is hyperbola

Tags: matrices, conic-sections

I have a question about the hyperbola matrix. In this question, I should find a matrix that is the hyperbola.

I know that if the determinant of a symmetric matrix be less than zero it'll be the hyperbola.

$$M_1=\begin{pmatrix}1&\frac{1}{2}&1\\ \frac{1}{2}& 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}\qquad M_2=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 3 \\ 0 & 1 & 7 \\ 3 & 7 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: So, the problem is, you don't know how to calculate the determinant of a matrix?

Comment: No. I know about the determinant of a matrix, but both of these matrices are symmetric and have determinants less than zero and I must choose one of them.

Comment: Well, if you are right about both matrices having negative determinant, and if you are right about that implying that each is a hyperbola, and if you are right that you must choose one of them, then just choose one of them, and you'll be OK. What's the problem?

Comment: this is a question in my exam, and we must choose the right answer, I mean one of them should be right. I am worried about my score.

Comment: Matrices aren't hyperbolas, so the question is literally nonsense. What you're really asking, presumably, is the following: which of the two matrices $M_1$, $M_2$ represents a quadratic form $q(x)=x^TMx$ whose graph is a hyperbola, where $x$ is represented using homogeneous coordinates? If that's what you mean, you should say so.

Comment: If you are saying that both answers are right, and that only one answer is right, then you have more to worry about than your score on an exam; you have proved that Mathematics is inconsistent, and that means the entire Universe is about to fall apart. So I'd encourage you to test all the statements and assumptions you have made here, and see whether just maybe one of them is wrong.

Comment: @symplectomorphic. Yes I mean this.